# Picture box not updating its content

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Sorry for my bad English... Hello there, I have made this picture box but whenever I try to load a new image in there, it doesn't show anything, just an empty picture box control. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
var loadImage = new BackgroundWorker();
loadImage.RunWorkerAsync();

// The stuff that is being executed in the backgroundworker.
loadImage.DoWork += (o, args) =>
    {
        // Loop through the list of items to find the matching picture.
        foreach (var item in listItems)
        {
            if (item.Name == name)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Get the image.
                    var request = WebRequest.Create(item.Picture);
                    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                        args.Result = image;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    };

// Execute this when the backgroundworker is finished.
loadImage.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, args) =>
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = (Image)args.Result;
        Application.DoEvents();
    };
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? If so, could you please tell me what?

Comment: Have you debugged to know whether or not you are assigning a valid `Image` to `args.Result` in the `DoWork` code?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Yes, it assigns the image.

Comment: Why you are running the background worker **before** of attach your delegates?

Comment: @HuorSwords I actually have no idea... This seems to be the problem. Sorry for the waste of time, I really didn't know why this happend. Thanks :). Stupid me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I comment you directly on your question, and to make it as an answer, you are running the background worker **before** of attaching your delegates.

Probably, you only just need exchange the order in your code.